# RxSwift Text field Delegate Methods

Tags: ios, swift3, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift. I need to ask how can I bind textField delegate methods using RxSwift like textFieldShouldReturn or textViewDidBeginEditing.

Answer (score 3):

This will bind `textfield` delegate methods

```
textfield.rx.controlEvent([.EditingDidBegin]).asObservable().subscribe(on:{_ in 
    print("edit begin")
 }).addDisposableTo(disposer)
```

Answer (score 0):

RxSwift, RxSwiftExt, RxCocoa 5.0:

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin).subscribe(onNext: { () in

}, onError: { (error) in

}, onCompleted: {

}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is one way of getting the text only when editing is done

```
cell.nameLabel.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd).map{return
                        cell.nameLabel.text!
                    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's supose you have a `viewModel`. For instance:

```
class ViewModel {
    var name: Variable<String>
    // more properties ...
}
```

Then, in your `viewController`:

```
textField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .bindTo(viewModel.name)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

In your `viewController` you have to import `RxSwift` and `RxCocoa`